# How do I break the sentence in Project section or make this particular sentence fit inside the page?

Tags: cv

[image: The line in the project section is not fitting inside the page]

The following is the code used-

```
%-------------------------
% Resume in Latex
% Author : Jake Gutierrez
% Based off of: https://github.com/sb2nov/resume
% License : MIT
%------------------------

\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\input{glyphtounicode}


%----------FONT OPTIONS----------
% sans-serif
% \usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans}
% \usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
% \usepackage[sfdefault]{noto-sans}
% \usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}

% serif
% \usepackage{CormorantGaramond}
% \usepackage{charter}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% Adjust margins
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.0in}

\urlstyle{same}

\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-4pt}\scshape\raggedright\large
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule \vspace{-5pt}]

% Ensure that generate pdf is machine readable/ATS parsable
\pdfgentounicode=1

%-------------------------
% Custom commands
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[1]{
  \item\small{
    {#1 \vspace{-2pt}}
  }
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
  \vspace{-2pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubSubheading}[2]{
    \item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textit{\small#1} & \textit{\small #2} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeProjectHeading}[2]{
    \item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \small#1 & #2 \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[1]{\resumeItem{#1}\vspace{-4pt}}

\renewcommand\labelitemii{$\vcenter{\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}$}

\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.15in, label={}]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-5pt}}

%-------------------------------------------
%%%%%%  RESUME STARTS HERE  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

%----------HEADING----------
% \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
%   \textbf{\href{http://sourabhbajaj.com/}{\Large Sourabh Bajaj}} & Email : \href{mailto:sourabh@sourabhbajaj.com}{sourabh@sourabhbajaj.com}\\
%   \href{http://sourabhbajaj.com/}{http://www.sourabhbajaj.com} & Mobile : +1-123-456-7890 \\
% \end{tabular*}

\begin{center}
    \textbf{\Huge \scshape Mohmad Afzal Mohmad Sidik}  \vspace{1pt}
    \small +919591562569 $|$\ \href{mailto:afzal_sidik@hotmail.com}{\underline{afzal_sidik@hotmail.com}} $|$ 
    \href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/m-afzal-sidik/}{\underline{https://www.linkedin.com/in/m-afzal-sidik/}} 
    \end{center}


%-----------EDUCATION-----------
\section{Education}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \resumeSubheading
      {Presidency University Bengaluru, India}{Aug. 2017 -- May 2021}
      {Bachelor of Technology in Petroleum Engineering }{8.94 CGPA}
    \resumeSubheading
      {Jain College, India}{Aug. 2016 -- May 2017}
      {Higher Secondary School }{75.66 \% } 
    \resumeSubheading
      {St. Xavier’s High School, India}{Aug. 2014 -- May 2015}
      {Secondary School}{80.57 \%}
  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd

%-----------Project-----------
\section{Project}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart

    \resumeSubheading
      {Synthesis of Nanocomposites with Surfactant for Improving Properties of Water Based Drilling Fluid}{June 2020 -- Present}
      {Texas A\&M University}{College Station, TX}
      \resumeItemListStart
        \resumeItem{Developed a REST API using FastAPI and PostgreSQL to store data from learning management systems}
        \resumeItem{Developed a full-stack web application using Flask, React, PostgreSQL and Docker to analyze GitHub data}
        \resumeItem{Explored ways to visualize GitHub collaboration in a classroom setting}
      \resumeItemListEnd
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the MWE already loads the `tabularx` package, you could simply change the original definition of `\resumeSubheading` to make use of `tabularx` and its `X` type column, for example as follows:

```
\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
  \vspace{-2pt}\item
    \begin{tabularx}{0.97\textwidth}[t]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X@{\qquad}r}
      \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
    \end{tabularx}\vspace{-7pt}
}
```